# Search by values in JSON column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table, which contains column with JSON value, for instance:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"components": [{"label": "greeting 1", "components": [{"label": "hello", "value": 10}, {"label":"hi", "value": 20}]}]} |
| 2 | {"components": [{"label": "greeting 2", "components": [{"label": "aloha", "value": 30}, {"label":"hola", "value": 40}]}]} |

I need to search for records, which contain some values in label or value or root or sub-components.
I've started with query like:

```
    select DISTINCT id, value
from TABLE
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(TABLE.value, '$.components'))
                              WITH (LABEL varchar(255) '$.label',
                                  VALUE varchar(255) '$.value') as jsonValues
WHERE jsonValues.LABEL like '%greeting%'
   OR jsonValues.VALUE like '%1%'
```

I've simplified JSON in example. In reallity it's more complex and have more fields and values, that should not be considered during search. That's why just simple LIKE by TABLE.value field doesn't suit.
But stuck in search of nested components.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Use a `LIKE`? JSON  is just an `nvarchar` at the end of the day.

Comment: I've added current version, when I stuck. All examples I've found so far are actually just make search in some simple json.

Comment: Are you able to change the format of your JSON?  I don't understand why you are not using values like `greeting 1` and `greeting 2` as property names if consistent across your data or holding the various `greeting` values within a `greeting` array?  Your `label` and `components` set up is making this much harder than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have many layers of nested JSON objects, you will need to specify to SQL Server that you need to dig through all those layers.  That you have a `label` and `components` property for each layer is an added (and likely unecessary) complexity that also needs to be handled.  In your 'simplified JSON' example there are 5 layers that need to be queried through, with care taken to apply filters at the appropriate levels to ensure all the nested properties are returned.

Suffice to say, this is less than ideal and would benefit significantly from a less convoluted JSON schema.

### Query

```
declare @t table(id int,[value] nvarchar(1000));
insert into @t values
 (1,'{"components": [{"label": "greeting 1", "components": [{"label": "hello", "value": 10}, {"label":"hi", "value": 20}]}]}')
,(2,'{"components": [{"label": "greeting 2", "components": [{"label": "aloha", "value": 30}, {"label":"hola", "value": 40}]}]}')
;

select g.Greeting
      ,v.GreetingLabel
      ,v.GreetingValue
from @t as t
    cross apply openjson(t.[value],'$')
        with(Greetings nvarchar(max) 'strict $.components' as json) as j    -- Use of optional strict keyword requires that the property exists within the JSON object
    cross apply openjson(j.Greetings,'$')
        with(Greeting nvarchar(50) 'strict $.label'
            ,Components nvarchar(max) 'strict $.components' as json
            ) as g
    cross apply openjson(g.Components,'$')
        with(GreetingLabel nvarchar(50) 'strict $.label'
            ,GreetingValue int 'strict $.value'
            ) as v
where g.Greeting like 'greeting%'
    and v.GreetingValue = 10;
```

---

### Output

| Greeting | GreetingLabel | GreetingValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| greeting 1 | hello | 10 |

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need!